# Location Regex for / and sub url

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I can't figure this out, how can I use regex to determine if the url has sub url?

```
location / {
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200 'healthy 1';
}


location ^/(.*)/$ {
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200 'healthy 2';
}
```

When I tried accessing `https://example.com/` it shows healthy 1, I tried accessing `https://example.com/dynamicroute/` it shows also healthy  1.

I would like to show `https://example.com/` healthy 1
and `https://example.com/dynamicroute/`  healthy  2.

Comment: The syntax for the [regular expression location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) is incorrect. You are missing the regular expression operator, either `~` or `~*`.